# Eliminate pointer resolution on call of function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization, function-pointers

I have a really strange question (I know, these types of optimizations are whacky and 99% of the time useless, but this is just an interesting case):
Suppose we have a struct with 1 method and 1 function pointer, that is assigned at RT. Considering when the functions are identical, the call to function pointer will require an additional pointer resolution and thus little-bit slower (where a method call is just a static offset).
Can we somehow eliminate this pointer resolution? (given that our dynamically assigned function pointer will never change afterwards)
The only solution I've thought of was to declare this "function pointer" as a static array of bytes, copy the code there, set memory to be executable and call it. That way the call also be identical to a "method" call.
Are there any other ways to achieve this strange run-time "linking"? (if you can call it this way :))

Comment: Have you: a) checked that there is a performance difference in your case, b) checked that the compiler doesn't optimise away the function pointer anyway? Since this is a VERY common operation, many compilers will optimize this sort of thing. Your solution with runtime generated code will require a function pointer to point at the generated code anyway, since it won't be a "code symbol".

Comment: Yes. I wrote a simple benchmark and there is a difference. But this is not "my case". Its a hypothetical question on how to fiddle with c++ compiler and runtime :) Is there a way to generate such "code symbol"?

Comment: In short, no. Code is not generated on the fly in C or C++. Symbols are resolved at compile time, one resolved function call can never be more than one thing - to do that, you need function pointers, that's why they exist. In my measurements, there's tiny differences, and most of the time the overhead is less than the alternative overhead of if's and other solutions to "you need two different bits of code here".